# Cant link to Python with FindPython cmake module

Tags: python, cmake

I'm trying to link to Python interpreter so I can run some python code in my C++ app. I'm using CMake 3.12 as a build system. It has a new module to load Python and the docs says that I should link to `Python::Interpreter`. This is my code:

In root `CMakeLists.txt` I have:

```
find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter)
```

I have a subdirectory which adds some more subdirs depending on the found libraries:

```
if (TARGET Python::Interpreter)
    add_subdirectory(Plotter)
endif()
```

Finally, in my application I link to Python:

```
set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
    plotter.cpp
)

set(HEADERS
    plotter.h
)

set(RESOURCES
    resources.qrc)

add_executable(Plotter ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} ${RESOURCES})
target_link_libraries(Plotter Qt5::Core fmt::fmt Python::Interpreter)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Target "Plotter" links to target "Python::Interpreter" but the target was not found.
```

This is really strange, because I'm explicitly checking the Python target exists before adding the application using it.

Any idea what its wrong here?